# Center-aligned DIVs

Tags: css, html

I am newbie in CSS, so please help me with my issue.

How I can to make wide DIV (name it "huge"), which positioned to have same center as base DIV (call him "thin") which is smaller than "huge". While "huge" have fixed dimensions, "thin" should be width:auto ("rubber").

Any ideas ?

Comment: The weird and specific naming instructions make this sound like homework...If it is, please tag it as such and people will be more willing to help you.

Comment: Why not show us the actual html and the desired outcome? :) `margin: 0 auto;` is the best way of centering a fixed width div.

Comment: hmmmmmm. Huge! thin! sounds like Laurel and Hardy

Comment: How do you mean so - http://jsfiddle.net/dadsy/

Comment: I'd try margin: 0 auto; right like you wrote, but I think it is not works for DIVs which wider than container (because it should be position:absolute, right ?). I am novice and I can be wrong. English is not my native language, so I just try to explain better. It is not homework, of course. Look here, please: [link]http://decor.svn2ftp.ru[/link] in the header. There is jQuery plug-in Roundabout, which using big DIV to store the picture "wheel". And small div which has rubber width, from which I want to see a part of that "wheel". Did you understand what I want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<div id="outer" style="width:700px; margin: 0 auto; border:1px solid black;">
   <div id="inner" style="width:auto; margin: 0 auto; text-align:center; border:1px solid red;">
      some text
   </div>
</div>
```

The section `margin: 0px auto;` means: set top and bottom margin to 0px, and left and right to auto (this creates centering of a `div`). The part `text-align:center` is self-explaining - centers the text inside. Borders are added to show you that it's working as you want.

Comment: Please look this [link]http://imageshack.us/f/832/thinhuge.jpg/  (sorry, but hand drown image is just faster :) ). This picture is describing what I mean.

Comment: @Jonas I know about positioning one div inside of another within margin: 0 auto; but it is not working for my situation :(

Comment: I still have problems understanding what you want to achieve. The link you posted (decor.svn2ftp.ru) is your site, yes? Can you post a screenshot what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Look here please: http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/4701/decorl.png I've made two images with window size 1600px and 1280px. It should display exactly what I want to achieve. You can see part of prev and next images positioned left and right from "main" image, which positioned on the center. Red border and horizontal scrollbar I want to remove, of course.

Answer (score 0):

`There is jQuery plug-in Roundabout, which using big DIV to store the picture...`

I think you may missunderstod the concept used by reference plugin. Because those element which seems bigger (as a background) actually can be in a same size with those element which seems "thin". Checkout : http://jsfiddle.net/toopay/JMp88/